# How do I create a customized Content Block

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

While editing/creating an email within "Email Studio"/"contentbuilder" you currently have the choice of embedding the following blocks by drag/drop:

- Button
- Free form
- HTML Image
- Text
- AB test
- Dynamic Content
- External Content
- Image Carousel
- Einstein Content
- Reference Content
- Social Follow
- Social Share

I would like to add additional blocks to the current possible blocks. I have seen this done - but I don't know how to.

The function of the additional block could be eg. "Interactive block", "Last 3 purchase" etc - and should be developed and maintained by ourselves.

It might have been based on https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk - but its hard to say based on the current documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Content SDK is complete. As per the [readme](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk), it exposes the following five JavaScript methods to use in your Custom Blocks:

- `getContent(callback)` - callback gets passed a content string
- `setContent(contentString, callback)` - callback gets passed a confirmation content string
- `getData(callback)` - callback gets passed an object with custom block metadata
- `setData(dataObject, callback)` - callback gets passed a confirmation object
- `setSupercontent(contentString, callback)` - callback gets passed a confirmation superContent string

The developer documentation for the Content SDK [is available here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/content-sdk.htm).

Note that you can't deploy a block to production at the moment — this will be available in the April release. However, in the meantime, there's a simple test app you can use at https://blocktester.herokuapp.com/