Representing a custom Content Block in the Blocks pane of the Template Builder
I am working on template setup for non-html users- if I define a custom Content Block for a specific element(a button configured with certain colors and sizes, or a header block made in a HTML element) then they are functionally drag-and-drop from the 'Content' pane.
My question is, how can I have these custom content blocks represented in the 'Blocks' pane?
I already have Code Snippets containing several of my desired elements, but the functionality is better reproduced and more easily edited in the Content Block interface.
A similar question was asked 6 years ago but did not expound on its resolution.

It requires external hosting.  Details can be found here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/210285/5202
